# PHP counter issue using flock()

Tags: php, counter, flock

I have a problem with a counter. I need to count two variables, separated with a |, but sometimes the counter doesn't increase a variable's value.

numeri.txt (the counter):

`5240|593389`

This is the PHP script:

```
$filename="numeri.txt";
$fp=fopen($filename,"r");
if(!flock($fp,LOCK_SH))
{
    while(true)
    {
        usleep(100000);
        if(flock($fp,LOCK_SH))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
$contents=fread($fp,filesize($filename));
flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
$fp=fopen($filename,'a');
if(!flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
{
    while(true)
    {
        usleep(100000);
        if(flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
ftruncate($fp,0);
$contents=explode("|",$contents);
$clicks=$contents[0];
$impressions=$contents[1]+1;
fwrite($fp,$clicks."|".$impressions);
flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

I set the counter to the right value but after 3-4 days the counter hasn't counted about 50 impressions (the number after "|")

How to fix the code?

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1) There is still the opportunity to do a read, another process to write the file, then this process write the file. Millisecond timing required, but it's possible.

2) You don't actually verify the "open" works - it can fail.

The solution is to firstly check for open failure and retry, and secondly do one lock - exclusive. Paraphrased code:

```
while (!$fh = fopen($file, 'c+')) {   // Read write, do not truncate, place pointer at start.
    usleep(100000);
}
while (!flock(LOCK_EX)) {
    usleep(100000);
}
$content = fread();
// Process content...
ftruncate();
fseek(0);  // Or frewind();
fwrite();
fclose();  // Also releases the lock.
```

Comment: Do I have to use the usleep() function both with fopen and with flock?

Comment: Both can fail, so yes. Ideally you'll have a counter that stops looping forever.

Comment: I did it but now, after 8 hours it counts two values more. Why?

Comment: Because you're calling it two times more than you should (e.g. testing it?) Or the thing you're comparing two counted two too few? It _could_ still count under (if it errorred) but can't see how it could count over...

Comment: Now it should be 600404 but it's 600379 (25 less). I used while true with usleep with all the functions (like fopen, ftruncate, flock etc.) What do I have to do?

Comment: I can't say - all I can do is point out the potential flaws in your code that may have caused the inital issue. Now you need ot look elsewhere. To start: 1) are you sure the 600404 is accurate? What calculates/stores this, and could that have a fault? 2) Are you sure the script is getting called each and every time? Any timeouts? Log if the script is called (apache log if through apache). 3) Anything in the php error log - there may be some other error preventing it from running, and that should appear in the log.

Comment: 1) The file that counts 600404 loads all user files and sums a variable, but it's a bit slow, so I had to make a counter, number.txt. So, the first file is accurate, but the counter sometimes is wrong.
2)Yes it is
3)The error log is empty.

Comment: Can you prove point "2"? Can you prove the correct user files are being created? If there anyother code in the file that could stop the file updater running. The fact you had it counting high and then counting low is proof that something else is going on. Only you can check that bit.